# Change icon on InputBox

Tags: winforms

I changed the main icon used on a WinForms project.  I updated the icon in project properties, and also the icon property on a number of forms in the project.  However, when I display a InputBox the old project icon is still displayed in the task bar for the input box.

```
string userInput = Interaction.InputBox("Enter Your Favorite Color.", "Red", String.Empty, -1, -1);
```

Any ideas out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dan, You will have to update the Icon in the Add/Remove programs. It takes the icon which is registered when the application is installed.